# Voltage Bridging (Impedance bridging) Question in Cascade Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I understand that impedance bridging in audio applications is simply a voltage divider so by making output impedance of first device as low as possible and input of the second device as high as possible we get better results for transmission and power loss.

How can i calculate an amplifiers impedance so i can create second amplifier accordingly and connect them cascaded. I provided an amplifier design of Texas Ins. 1000Hz low pass with 1500Hz stopband. Are these resistors R1_Sx, R2_Sx at input of opamps selected according to this impedance bridging concept. If so, how do we calculate the impedance at input and output of each cascade block?
[image]

Secondly could you provide me some sources on this topic that i can learn for audio applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you choose an op-amp for a particular design, you choose it with knowledge of the various significant parameters it has that relate to what the design performance expectations are.

One of these parameters can be the closed-loop output impedance i.e. what output impedance it projects given its open-loop gain and bandwidth. In a lot of cases, the highest frequency of interest to the design is usually well-within the bandwidth of the the op-amp but, if you need a lot of gain in the circuit you have to factor that in and this is called gain-bandwidth-product.

So, if you choose an op-amp with a GBP of 1 MHz it can be relied upon in a design to have a 3 dB point that is 100 kHz with a gain of ten or, a 3 dB point that is 10 kHz with a gain of 100.

But, the down side is that the output impedance is starting to rise at the higher frequencies and, this could become problematic. Having to fight gain-bandwidth limitations and then output loading effects means that you have to be careful.

Consider an op-amp that has a natural open-loop output impedance of 100 ohms across the spectrum (a bit simplistic of course). When you apply negative feedback, the major benefit is that the closed-loop output impedance drops massively (due to the massive open-loop gain that the op-amp has). If at higher frequencies that open-loop gain is pushed to the gain-bandwidth extremes, any extra loading effects can make things worse. At lower frequencies there won't be a problem of course.

I see in your design that it uses a TL071 but I don't think this is modern enough for the data sheet to help you. However, many data sheets of modern devices either tell you open-loop output impedance (thus allowing you to calculate the closed loop output impedance) (usually TI) or they give examples of the closed loop output impedance at certain gains (ADI is notable in my experience).

So, pick a device that specifies the output impedance in the data sheet or physically test it. Having said all of that the basic rule is to assume the output impedance is zero and try and make loading effects from input circuits as high as possible but, this isn't always the case.

Comment: I understand the opamp output impdance by device. Besides that do the resistors in design have any purpose for impedance bridging rather than rc filtering. I noticed they are going by decreasing from one stage to another.

Comment: All the resistors in your design will not significantly load the previous stage. The final stage having significantly lower resistors needn't be that way but, it seems that the filter characteristic of that stage is intended to be a higher frequency roll-off with much higher Q as is typical of a 4th order, unity gain, sallen key filter. It seems they may have focused on the 10 nF being the same for both stages and worked around from there.

Comment: Andy thanks for your answers. It was really helpful. I want to ask one more, you said other opamps may indicate open loop impedance so i can calculate closed loop. What is the correct way of doing this. For example lets say in the design above we have open loop impedance of 100. What would be the closed loop for stage 2 or 3 or 1. Sorry to bother again.

Comment: Closed loop impedance depends on open loop gain so if open loop impedance is 100 and open loop gain is 10000 then the act of unity gain feedback produces an output impedance of 0.01 ohms. As circuit gain rises and frequency rises, closed loop impedance also rises. Review the open loop gain of typical opamps to see the effect at higher frequencies.